# Bash Command for Run All .Rmd files

Tags: r, bash, command-line, r-markdown

I have 4 .Rmd files that I sequentially run to clean, push, and build a postgres database. While I am in this process of developing the DB I want to be able to create a bash function in which from the command line I can invoke all 4 .Rmd files being executed sequentially.

What is the bash command for run all?

I know I can render .Rmd files with

```
function renderschema() {

Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('file.Rmd')"

}
```

But what is the equivalent of "run all" (command+shift+r) from the command line?

Ideally I would like something as below but instead of Render it just runs the script.

```
function build_db() {

Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('file_1.Rmd')"

Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('fil_2.Rmd')"

Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('fil_3.Rmd')"

}
```

Comment: that returns ```Error in -title : invalid argument to unary operator```

Comment: and ```Rscript -e "file_1.Rmd"
Error: object 'file_1.Rmd' not found``` does not work

Comment: I have a great deal of trouble believing that a function that _only_ calls `Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('file.Rmd')"` gets different behavior from R than a function that calls that and then two other R commands after. Indeed, I don't believe it at all: R has no way of knowing what other code is in the same shell function that started it.

Comment: BTW, `function somefunc() {` should be replaced with just `somefunc() {` without the `function` -- see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: ...anyhow -- if you're only dealing with simple filenames, you might consider something like `for file in *.Rmd; do Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('$file')"; done`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know I can just render the files but I was hoping to find a more sleek way to run the code then creating .html outputs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. (Part of it is that I don't know what this "run all" thing you're talking about is, so it's hard to know what an alternative would be).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was overthinking all of this. I wanted to prevent a .html output file from when the document is rendered. All I had to do is remove the output option in the yaml.... duhhhh. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

You can try doing something [like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184502/bash-how-to-run-a-command-after-the-previous-finished) where you wait for the previous command to exit successfully before running the next:

```
#!/bin/bash
command1 && command2 && command3
```

Comment: It is not the sequential running that I am confused about. It is the actual command to use in which will run but not render a .Rmd file from the CML